# excel userform is listing variables instead of adding

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  MultiPage1.Value = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Cmbo_A_Change()    
    If Cmbo_A = "Clay" Then
        TextBox1 = 20
    ElseIf Cmbo_A = "Sand" Then
        TextBox1 = 35
    Else
        TextBox1 = 35
    End If

    If Cmbo_A = "Clay" Then
        TextBox2 = 18
    ElseIf Cmbo_A = "Sand" Then
        TextBox2 = 16
    Else
        TextBox2 = 19
    End If    
End Sub

Private Sub Cmbo_P_Change()    
    If Cmbo_P = "Clay" Then
        TextBox70 = 20
    ElseIf Cmbo_P = "Sand" Then
        TextBox70 = 35
    Else
        TextBox70 = 35
    End If

    If Cmbo_P = "Clay" Then
        TextBox69 = "18"
    ElseIf Cmbo_P = "Sand" Then
        TextBox69 = 16
    Else
        TextBox69 = 19
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Cmbo_W_Change()
    If Cmbo_W = "Clay" Then
        TextBox15 = 18
    ElseIf Cmbo_W = "Sand" Then
        TextBox15 = 16
    ElseIf Cmbo_W = "Concrete" Then
        TextBox15 = 23
    Else
        TextBox15 = 20
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    MultiPage1.Value = 1

    Pi = 4 * Atn(1)
    i = TextBox1.Value * (Pi / 180)

    q = TextBox70.Value * (Pi / 180)

    Dim hw As Double
    hw = TextBox5.Value
    Dim tw As Double
    tw = TextBox6.Value
    Dim h1 As Double
    h1 = TextBox7.Value
    Dim h2 As Double
    h2 = TextBox8.Value
    Dim bp As Double
    bp = TextBox9.Value
    Dim bw As Double
    bw = TextBox10.Value
    Dim ba As Double
    ba = TextBox11.Value

    TextBox30.Value = hw * bw
    TextBox31.Value = TextBox30.Value * TextBox15.Value
    TextBox32.Value = bp + (bw / 2)
    TextBox33.Value = TextBox32.Value * TextBox31.Value

    TextBox38.Value = tw * (bp + bw + ba)
    TextBox39.Value = TextBox38.Value * TextBox15.Value
    TextBox40.Value = (bp + ba + bw) / 2
    TextBox41.Value = TextBox40.Value * TextBox39.Value

    TextBox34.Value = hw * bw
    TextBox35.Value = TextBox34.Value * TextBox2.Value
    TextBox36.Value = bp + bw + (ba / 2)
    TextBox37.Value = TextBox36.Value * TextBox35.Value

    TextBox42.Value = (h2 - tw) * bp
    TextBox43.Value = TextBox42.Value * TextBox69.Value
    TextBox44.Value = bp / 2
    TextBox45.Value = TextBox44.Value * TextBox43.Value

    TextBox17.Value = Application.Round(Tan(Pi / 4 - (TextBox1.Value * (Pi / 180) / 2)) ^ 2, 2)

    o = TextBox70.Value * (Pi / 180)
    TextBox18.Value = Application.Round(Tan(Pi / 4 + (TextBox1.Value * (Pi / 180) / 2)) ^ 2, 2)
    TextBox19.Value = Application.Round(TextBox71.Value * (ba + bw) / 2, 2)
    TextBox20.Value = Application.Round(TextBox17.Value * bp, 2)

    TextBox25.Value = Application.Round(TextBox17.Value * TextBox71.Value * (hw + tw), 2)
    TextBox21.Value = TextBox2.Value * TextBox34.Value
    TextBox80.Value = TextBox19.Value
    TextBox81.Value = TextBox20.Value
    TextBox22.Value = TextBox69.Value * TextBox42.Value
    TextBox26.Value = ((bw + tw) ^ 2 * TextBox17.Value * TextBox2.Value) / 2
    TextBox27.Value = TextBox18.Value * TextBox69.Value * h2
    TextBox28.Value = h2 ^ 2 + (TextBox69.Value * TextBox18.Value)

    TextBox58.Value = (h2 - tw) / 2 + tw
    TextBox72.Value = TextBox27.Value
    TextBox59.Value = TextBox58.Value * TextBox72.Value

    TextBox60.Value = h2 / 3
    TextBox73.Value = TextBox28.Value
    TextBox61.Value = TextBox60.Value * TextBox73.Value

    TextBox54.Value = ba - (ba + bw) / 2
    TextBox80.Value = TextBox19.Value
    TextBox55.Value = TextBox54.Value * TextBox80.Value

    TextBox56.Value = bp / 2
    TextBox81.Value = TextBox20.Value
    TextBox57.Value = TextBox56.Value * TextBox81.Value

    TextBox74.Value = TextBox25.Value

    TextBox77.Value = TextBox26.Value

    TextBox75.Value = (bp + ba + bw) / 2
    TextBox78.Value = (h1 + h2) / 3
    TextBox76.Value = TextBox74.Value * TextBox75.Value

    TextBox79.Value = TextBox77.Value * TextBox78.Value

    TextBox24.Value = TextBox31.Value + TextBox39.Value + TextBox35.Value + TextBox43.Value + TextBox80.Value + TextBox81.Value
    TextBox29.Value = Tan(2 * TextBox70.Value * (Pi / 180) / 3) + TextBox24.Value

    TextBox23.Value = TextBox30.Value + TextBox38.Value * TextBox15.Value

    TextBox62.Value = TextBox33.Value + TextBox37.Value + TextBox41.Value + TextBox45.Value + TextBox55.Value + TextBox57.Value + TextBox61.Value + TextBox59.Value
    TextBox63.Value = TextBox76.Value + TextBox79.Value
    TextBox64.Value = (TextBox31.Value + TextBox39.Value + TextBox35.Value + TextBox43.Value + TextBox72.Value + TextBox73.Value + TextBox80.Value + TextBox81.Value) * Tan(2 * (i / 3)) + (bp + ba + bw)

    TextBox65.Value = TextBox62.Value / TextBox63.Value

    If TextBox65 >= 1.5 And TextBox65 < 2 Then
        TextBox66 = "wall stable"
    ElseIf TextBox65 < 1.5 Then
        TextBox66 = "wall unstable"
    Else
        TextBox66 = "wall overdesigned"
    End If

    TextBox67.Value = TextBox64.Value / TextBox29.Value

    If TextBox67 >= 1.5 And TextBox67 < 2 Then
        TextBox68 = "wall stable"
    ElseIf TextBox67 < 1.5 Then
        TextBox68 = "wall unstable"
    Else
        TextBox68 = "wall overdesigned"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    UserForm1.PrintForm
End Sub
```

This is currently my code for an assignment for uni. I am having troubles with lines textbox24, textbox62,textbox63. in the userform, it would list all the decimal outputs as for example 26.755.742.6, and so on, it is not adding those variables, any help would be much appreciated, and sorry about the wall of text, first using this forum.

Comment: Try something like `TextBox24.Value = CDbl(TextBox31.Value) + ...`

Comment: yep, that fixed textbox24, but doing the same for textbox62,63 had no impact

Comment: Did you wrap all of the "TextboxXX.Value"  in CDbl()?

Comment: no, i did each variable seperately, but after abit of tweaking around, i got it to work with the cdbl(), thank you, ur a life saver